# How to embed custom plots in the H2O flow UI in Scala or R?

Tags: scala, h2o, sparkling-water

After some investigation, I have found out that the sparkling water H2O flow UI has a very limited set of plots - just Box plots, and distributions, for data visualization in Scala.

But if I want to use a third party library (**need recommendations on this**, I have already checked the Scala-charts library), how would I embed the generated plots in the H2O flow UI itself?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen a couple of examples of this over the years, but the real answer is this really isn’t supported well.

Here is a pointer to the best example I can remember:

https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/examples/flows/2016_H2O_Tour_Chicago.flow

If you really want to do this, the best guide is the source code of H2O Flow.